# Access DMax as query criteria, but Dmaxing groups of records, not entire query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I'm using Access 2007.

I have a query that has entries for the same record by they differ by order, like this:

```
Number       Sequence
100          1
100          2
100          3
101          1
101          2
102          1
102          2
102          3
102          4
```

And then I have another field that I want to only show a number on the last of the sequence for each number.  I tried this criteria:

```
IIf([Sequence]=DMax("Sequence","tbl_TimeReporting",""),[do my operation],"")
```

But this only shows a value on 102, sequence 4, because that's the max value for the whole query.  I want it to show a value on that, but also 100, sequence 3 and 101, sequence 2, because those are the max values for each #.  I hope that makes sense.

How might I go about doing this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: I believe your line of code is a part of SQL query. If so, why don't you show us complete query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a GROUP BY Query on the [Number] too. Something like,

```
SELECT 
    [Number],
    Max(Sequence) As MaxOfSeq
FROM
    tableName
GROUP BY 
    [Number];
```

This would give you a result like

```
Number  |   MaxOfSeq
--------+-----------
100     |   3
101     |   2
102     |   3
104     |   4
```